# Trying to fill textbox value with today's date only on visual basics

Tags: vb.net, date, textbox, basic

I am trying to fill a textbox value with the current date and I do not want the user to be able to change the date. I want to use a textbox and not a datepicker. I would like the form to load with today's date already loaded in the textbox, which I will then use in my insert query.

I want the date format of yyyy-MM-dd to be in the textbox memberregisterationdate.text. I am not sure where on my form I should put the code either.

Really stuck on this and I can't seem to find it anywhere
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to make it `Enabled = False` to disable it. You can load it in `Form_Load`:

```
memberregisterationdate.Text = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying that for ages. My code was very similar but must have been in the wrong place. Thanks again

Comment: Or you can use the textbox ReadOnly = True parameter instead of Enable = False.